# Setting Custom Properties on Files

Tags: file, properties

I have 200 files I need to upload regularly to sharepoint 365, users sync that folder with onedrive. Now, some guy has come along and added a bunch of "properties" for my files, such as "Category" and "Target Audience" to sharepoint. Now, I am a lazy bugger, so I have created a ps1 file with a bunch of functions to create, delete folders and create, delete, upload files and have an automated workflow to upload the files to sharepoint automagically. I now need to programmatically set these "properties" on the files.

When I use the browser to look at my files, I can set values for these properties via a drop-down or radio buttons.

I found these two sources:

https://www.sptrenches.com/2014/12/write-and-get-user-profile-properties.html

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21801.sharepoint-a-complete-guide-to-get...

These make me believe that this "should work":

```
//$file is Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File


PS > $file.Properties.FieldValues["Category"]="Training"

PS > $file.Update()
```

However, when I do that, nothing happens. If I do:

```
//ctx is Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext

PS > $file.Properties.FieldValues["Category"]="Training"
PS > $ctx.Load($file.Properties)

PS > $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

I get an error:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Field or property "Category" does not exist."
At line:1 char:1
+ $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerException
```

Now, I know there is a combination of the above that works, because I managed it twice, by mixing the above, but I am unable to get a consistent behavior.

Another thing, I tried to find the properties in the list in question:

```
//$List is Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List



$List.Fields | select InternalName
```

I do not get Category or target audience

Now, i can manually set the fields on the files, but that is not an option for me ... any thoughts, what am I doing wrong ? If there is a way I can help you help me, please do advise ;-).

Comment: Which kind of field are those two fields, choice, lookup or managed metadata?

Comment: How could I find that out programmatically ?

Comment: It is easy to verify in the gui: go to library settings, locate the field and you should be able to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am an idiot.

```
$file.Poperties | get-member
[...]
Item                         ParameterizedProperty System.Object Item(string fieldName) {get;set;} <--- get AND set
[...]
FieldValues                  Property              System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,System.Object] FieldValues {get;} <---- get only!
```

The following does work:

```
PS > $file.Properties.Item["Category"]="Training"
PS > $file.Update()
PS > $ctx.Load($file.Properties)
PS > $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```